# Перенаправление потока в файл - Bash

Tags: bash, openwrt, uart, stm32

Делаю устройство на OpenWrt, которое общается с STM32 по UART. Проблема заключается в следующем: контроллер посылает на сервер пакеты, когда я прослушиваю порт в терминале `cat /dev/ttyATH0`, пакеты выводятся ровные в следующем виде:

> echo
>   "REPLY=RECV_CAN:INDEX=2771:EID=01801FFF:CAN_DATA=52FF6F0667655051:CRC=B038"
>   echo
>   "REPLY=RECV_CAN:INDEX=2772:EID=02801FFF:CAN_DATA=53FF6F0650755652:CRC=85CF"
>   echo
>   "REPLY=RECV_CAN:INDEX=2773:EID=01801FFF:CAN_DATA=52FF6F0667655051:CRC=085F"
>   echo
>   "REPLY=RECV_CAN:INDEX=2774:EID=02801FFF:CAN_DATA=53FF6F0650755652:CRC=5D47"

Если я перенаправляю поток в файл `cat /dev/ttyATH0 > example.txt`, то часть данных теряется и пакеты имеют следующий вид:

> echo "REPLY=RCVCNIDX=26:I=20FFCN_AA53FF60755:R=F9"   echo
>   "REPLY=REC_CNIDX27:I=10FFCNDT=2FF67501CCAB"   echo
>   "REPLY=RECVCA:IDX=278ED081FFCN_AA5F6057552CC36F   echo
>   "REPYRC_CNIDX279ED=10FFCN_DATA=52FF6F0667501CC=BF

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В драйвере UART, в скорости потока, в частоте процессора (UART при скоростях больше 115200 и под различными ОС -- это весьма тяжёлая задача для процессора, использование других средств коммуникации позволит избежать подобных проблем).

Comment: Была такая проблема при скоростях выше 4800, длинные сообщения даже в терминал выводились не корректно. На 4800 cat стал работать корректно. Может для файла нужна скорость еще ниже? Но это уже слишком медленно...

Comment: Что интересно, cat /dev/ttyATH0 | tee /output.txt пишет четко

Comment: Очевидно, буферизация помогает избежать всплесков загрузки. По умолчанию буфер UART всего одна страничка памяти (4к), а вот с tee вполне похоже, что влючается дополнительная буферизация и он "успевает" сливать данные более длинными блоками.